# I used 10minutemail and my own phone number, is there a risk?

Tags: email, phone, identity-theft, risk, imei

I created a twitter account and used 10minuteemail, then twitter said my account was having automated behaviour, so I searched a temporary fake number to use but for the sake of lazyness I just put my own phone number. I removed it almost immediately.

Unfortunately twitter send back my number in plain sight. 10minutemail erases all mail but is generally site secure, isn't it full of crawling bots and such? Do I risk IMEI or identity theft?

Comment: Considering that telephone numbers for land lines are printed in books and given away for free ... and have been for years.  On top of the fact that emails are not encrypted and thus every twitter user that has ever entered there phone number has had there phone number emailed in clear text ... I think you are fine.

Comment: Well, I can be naive sometimes. We live in anothe rage where indenity theft is more relevant than before, tho. Am I wrong? Tnx for replying me. I wondere if that 10minutemail this would be less of more secure compared to a generic webmail.

Comment: What concern me is that aformentioned number is used alot with my various accout for 2-step verifications and similar security things.

Comment: If you had something to worry about ... then so would 319 million other twitter users.  While I wouldn't advise you randomly posting your internet on forums such as this ... even if you do the most you could expect is some amusing/annoying prank calls.

Comment: Well, in order for 2 factor auth to work ... they have to be able to receive texts / voice from the phone number ... gl achieving that w/ just a phone number

Comment: You're right, anyway, I was thinking about this particular case. Using a cellphone and a temporary email. I'm surely overparanoid but I head of sories of indentity theft that lead to breaking in mails et cetera.

Comment: Anyway, you,re right. I'm fantasizing to much. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The following people now know your phone number:

- Twitter
- The operators or 10minutemail
- Anyone breaking into one of the above services stealing data. (Note that 10minutemail isn't supposed to show your email to others, so some kind of security breach would be required.)

Is this a problem? Not really. There's not that much one can do with just a phone number. You might get some SMS or phone call spam, but I would not worry to much about it. Maybe it could be used in some kind of social enginering attack, but that is quite labour intensive and not something I would expect at random. If I were you, I would just forget about this whole thing.